# Implementing storage model optimisation with dependencies across time

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

Trying to put together a simple linear optimisation problem that has dependencies across time. It is a storage model where there are inflows coming into a storage and it needs to release water to maximise the water * price revenue stream - storage levels are carried over to the next period. There is a maximum storage level and maximum release amount per period.

I have no idea how to implement the constraint and setting up of the storage parameter in PULP. See my attempt below:

**EDIT**: How do I implement these 2 constraints:
1. storage[t+1] == storage[t] + inflow[t] - release[t] + spill[t]
2. storage[T] == storage[0] (so that end storage = start storage)
3. storage < maximum storage level for all t

Also not sure if I need really 'spill' as a variable as that can be inferred from constraint (1).

```
startstorage = 30
maxstorage = 35
maxrelease = 15

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'inflow':[5,3,13,62,11,1,5,9,7,8],
                          'PRICES':[1,2,3,1,3,5,3,4,2,6]})

#do I need to initialise storage and set an upper bound on storage?
#storage = [0] * len(data)
#storage[0] = startstorage

prob = pulp.LpProblem("My LP Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)
release = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('release',data.index, lowBound=0, upBound = maxrelease, cat='Continuous')
spill = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('spill',data.index, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
prob += sum([release[t] * data['PRICES'][t] for t in data.index])
# constraint (1)
prob += [storage[t+1] == storage[t] + data['inflow'][t] - release[t] + spill[t] for t in data.index[:-1]]
# constraint (2)
prob += storage[-1:] == storage[0] 

prob.solve()
```

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance!

Comment: I see that you are trying to describe the model in the comments of the code, but it would be more helpful if you included a full description of the model in the text of the question itself. Have you been able to mathematically formulate the problem and just need help implementing it in pulp? If so, please include the fully formulated model. If not, what parts are you stuck on mathematically?

Comment: Thanks Jolisber, I have edited the post to try clarify what I need help with (implementing the constraints to this problem, and setting up the initial parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I realised several rookie errors after reading through more examples. Here it is which achieves what I was after.

```
startstorage = 30
maxstorage = 35
maxrelease = 15

data = pd.DataFrame(data={'inflow':[5,3,13,62,11,1,5,9,7,8],'PRICES':[1,2,3,1,3,5,3,4,2,6]})

prob = pulp.LpProblem("My LP Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)
storage = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('storage',data.index, lowBound=0, upBound = maxstorage, cat='Continuous')
release = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('release',data.index, lowBound=0, upBound = maxrelease, cat='Continuous')
spill = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('spill',data.index, lowBound=0, cat='Continuous')
prob += lpSum([release[t] * data['PRICES'][t] for t in data.index])
for t in data.index[:-1]:
    prob += storage[t] + data['inflow'][t] - release[t] - spill[t] == storage[t+1]
prob += storage[0] == startstorage
prob += storage[9] == startstorage
prob.solve()
```